# How to set value for variable that refer to other class in constructor without parameter?

Tags: c#

I have declared a list of variable including variable that refer to another class.

```
public class order {

    private int primaryid;
    private string desc;
    private int customerid;
    private Customer customer;

}
```

And I already create the get and set methods. How can I assign value to variable customer in constructor without parameter?

```
public order(){
   primaryid = 0;
   desc = string.empty;
   customerid = 0;
   customer = ?
}
```

Comment: You can either do `customer = null` or `customer = new Customer()`, but if you're asking how to pass an existing customer through without a parameter you can't without creating a real bastardized bit of code.

Comment: thanks for the idea..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking to instantiate a new customer try this:

```
public order(){
   primaryid = 0;
   desc = string.empty;
   customerid = 0;
   customer = new Customer();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without any parameters you can only initialize the customer with a new instance.

```
customer = new Customer();
```

or if you are about to hard code the Customer properties, you can use

```
customer = new Customer{ *provide the initial values here* };
```

for eg, if customer has FirstName and LastName as its properties,

```
customer = new Customer{ FirstName = "someName" , LastName = "someLastName" };
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than setting customer to `null` or `new Customer()` then you can use one of two approaches:

Static variable:

```
void Main()
{
    order_helper.customer = new Customer();
    var order = new order();
}

public static class order_helper
{
    public static Customer customer;
}

public class order
{
    private int primaryid;
    private string desc;
    private int customerid;
    private Customer customer;

    public order()
    {
        primaryid = 0;
        desc = String.Empty;
        customerid = 0;
        customer = order_helper.customer;
    }
}
```

Or reflection:

```
    var field =
        typeof(order)
            .GetField("customer", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    var order = new order();
    field.SetValue(order, new Customer());
```